# Running desktop enviroment in docker in headless linux

Tags: linux, docker, x11

is it possible to run in headless linux, to be exact, linux with no desktop enviroment with GUI from inside docker.
(only if couldt be done differently with x server of some sort, but I would rather run everything within docker)

I want to run GUI only on occasions and I dont want it to share the userspace with the base system programs. Also I dont want to preserve the DE till the next occasion that is needed.

Comment: Why not? It must be possible.

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent Qubes?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible!

First let's create a docker volume to store the X11 socket:

```
docker volume create --name xsocket
```

Now we can create an image with X Server:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive' apt-get install -y xorg

CMD /usr/bin/X :0 -nolisten tcp vt1
```

Let us build it and start it and store the X11 socket in `xsocket` docker volume:

```
docker build . -t docker-x-server:latest
docker run --privileged -v xsocket:/tmp/.X11-unix -d docker-x-server:latest
```

Now we can run a GUI application in another docker container (yay!) and point it to our X server using `xsocket` volume:

```
docker run --rm -it -e DISPLAY=:0 -v xsocket:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro stefanscherer/xeyes
```

If you need input (like keyboard) install `xserver-xorg-input-evdev` package and add `-v /run/udev/data:/run/udev/data` since there's no [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) in containers by default.

You can even get rid of `--privileged` flag by granting `SYS_TTY_CONFIG` capability and binding some devices into container:

```
docker run --name docker-x-server --device=/dev/input --device=/dev/console --device=/dev/dri --device=/dev/fb0 --device=/dev/tty --device=/dev/tty1 --device=/dev/vga_arbiter --device=/dev/snd  --device=/dev/psaux --cap-add=SYS_TTY_CONFIG  -v xsocket:/tmp/.X11-unix  -d  docker-x-server:latest
```